How to apply changes to Airflow job_heartbeat_sec scheduler variable
So I've updated the value of job_heartbeat_sec in the [scheduler] section of airflow.cfg. I stopped and restarted the scheduler after updating the value of the variable. I expected the /health endpoint of the Webserver UI to only update the heartbeat timestamp every 20 seconds, but it is still using the default 5.
Is there something I'm missing in terms of steps to apply these changes? Thanks in advance.

If you are referring to the latest_scheduler_heartbeat value in /health endpoint , scheduler_heartbeat_sec is the config parameter you want to set here . Setting this value to 20 , will update the latest_scheduler_heartbeat value every 20 seconds. But this also means that the scheduler runs every 20 seconds according to airflow documentation  .
